# Finding out character 'a' from a file then count the lines in which the character is appeared

Tags: c++, pointers

Dont know how to do this. Tried something like below.Want more optimisation in code.
Everyting should be in one function only,
guide me how to open close a file,
how to find character in each line,
increase the counter.

```
void simpleFileIn(void) {

    string line;
    ifstream myfile("example.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(myfile, line)) {
            //found(line);
            size_t size = strlen(line);
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

the function simpleFileIn() should work, to open a file then close after work is done.
find out character a and count the integers.
want to close/ delete this question as i am in ban asking more help me. situation getting worse day after day

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please epxlain what you think this line does `*pptr=ptr;`. Especially what the  difference is between its effect on `pptr[0]` and `pptr[1]`.

Comment: Obligatory "use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays"

Comment: I'm not sure how so many people are asking "what are you really asking". To me it seems clear enough: OP wants to use his dynamically-allocated 2D array, but finds that he cannot. **The question is: why?** Answer: he's allocating it wrong: see all existing answers on this thread.

Comment: @Askish Kamble It is not allowed here to change question (especially after there are answers and you accept one). For new question, create new question (thread). Thanks.

Comment: I am banned from asking more questions @FilipKočica I cant ask a new one and  I need to deliver this Excel sheet as soon as possible. If i dont get right answer in time i can lead on wrong path,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocing array of pointers wrong.

First you have to allocate enough space for `row` pointers

```
int** pptr = new int* [rows];
```

For every pointer enough space for `col` integers

```
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    pptr[i] = new int [cols];
}
```

To delete arrays use `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Delete every individual row

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    delete [] pptr[i];
}
```

Then delte array of pointers

```
delete [] pptr;
```

There is no need to assigning `NULL` to deleted pointer since you wont use them again. Also in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

**[Here is the correct using of array of pointers.](https://ideone.com/rw14x8)**

---

Your mistakes

```
int* ptr = new int [rows];
int** pptr = new int* [cols];
*pptr=ptr;
```

- Swapped rows & cols
- Allocated memory only for first pointer/row, others were uninitialized -> UB
- Used `delete` instead of `delete[]`

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate rows in a loop as you go:

```
int** pptr = new int* [rows]; // <<== rows, not cols
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    pptr[i] = new int[cols]; // <<== Add this line
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
        cout<<"Enter value at "<<i<<j<<endl;
        cin>>pptr[i][j];
        cout<<"Value is "<<pptr[i][j]<<endl;
    }
}
```

You also need to delete individual rows before deleting the array of pointers to them. Use `delete[]` operator with square brackets:

```
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    delete[] pptr[i];
}
delete[] pptr;
```

You do not need to assign `NULL`s to deleted pointers, unless you plan to reuse the pointer for something else later on.

Answer (score 1):

So there seems to be some confusion with allocation. From your code

```
int* ptr = new int [rows];
int** pptr = new int* [cols];
*pptr=ptr;
```

you have now created to 1-dimensional arrays. You then dereference the `pptr` and assign to it `ptr` this is the same as

```
pptr[0] = ptr;
```

So you are only initializing the very first column. You want to change this code to be

```
int** pptr = new int* [cols];
for (int i = 0; i < cols; ++i) {
    pptr[i] = new int [rows];
}
```

This will allocate the memory properly

Answer (score 1):

You can create a constructor of sorts for your 2D array so that you have one-line bookkeeping:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T** new_( std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns )
{
  auto dsize = rows    * sizeof(T*);
  auto rsize = columns * sizeof(T);
  auto tsize = rows    * rsize;

  unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[ dsize + tsize ];
  T** result = (T**)data;
  T*  table  = (T*)(data + dsize);

  while (rows--) 
    result[ rows ] = table + rows * columns;

  return result;
}

int main()
{
  int m; std::cout << "m? ";  std::cin >> m;
  int n; std::cout << "n? ";  std::cin >> n;

  // Create the new matrix
  int** a = new_<int>( m, n );

  // Do stuff with a[ r ][ c ] here.
  // It looks and behaves JUST LIKE a normal 2D C array
  // in all respects EXCEPT one: &a != &(a[0][0]).
  // Use the latter when passing to a flat function!

  // Delete it
  delete [] a;
}
```

Enjoy the weirdness.